# Al verificar que esta correcto no me redirecciona

Tags: php, html, css, phpmyadmin

El inconveniente radica en que, al iniciar sesión y verificar las credenciales del usuario desde mi computadora, la aplicación me redireccionaba exitosamente a la página principal. Sin embargo, tras subir la aplicación al servidor de 000webhost, si bien la autenticación del usuario se lleva a cabo de manera correcta, la redirección ya no ocurre. Cabe destacar que he confirmado la correcta configuración de la base de datos y otros aspectos relevantes.

Código de comprobación con php

```php
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "id21021107_usuarios";
$pass = "********";
$db = "id21021107_usuarios";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if (!$conexion) {
    die("No se pudo conectar a la base de datos: " . mysqli_error());
}
?>
```

Archivo: index.php

```php
<?php
session_start();

include('conexion.php');

if (isset($_POST['Usuario']) && isset($_POST['Clave'])) {
    function validate($data){
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    $Usuario = validate($_POST['Usuario']);
    $Clave = validate($_POST['Clave']);

    if (empty($Usuario)) {
        header("Location: index.php?error=El usuario es requerido");
        exit();
    } elseif (empty($Clave)) {
        header("Location: index.php?error=La clave es requerida");
        exit();
    } else {
        $Clave = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $Clave);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario = '$Usuario' AND Clave = '$Clave'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

        if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['Usuario'] = $row['Usuario'];
            $_SESSION['Nombre_Completo'] = $row['Nombre_Completo'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            echo "Antes de la redirección"; 
            header('Location: paginaPrincipal.php');
            exit();
            echo "Después de la redirección";
        } else {
            header("Location: index.php?error=El usuario o la clave son incorrectas");
            exit();
        }
    }
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿A donde redirecciona exactamente?

Comment: Hola Fati, no podes enviar datos al navegador antes de llamar a `header` (_saca el `echo`_)

Comment: lo quiero redireccionar a la paginaPrincipal.php.
el echo que esta antes del header location y despues es para saber si lo toma o no y al comprobar  el echo de antes de la redireccion aparece pero el de despues no eso significa que el problema esta ahi pero nose